# How do I enable indigo themes on openedx

Tags: openedx

I want to change the theme of openedx deployed on the local virtual machine. Because I use is tutor Installation, so I try to introduce indijo plug-ins, in accordance with the https://github.com/overhangio/tutor-indigo Installation in the following steps to complete the Installation, But when I reopened openedx, I didn't see the theme change

Check if the installation failed and I wonder if I need to modify some other configuration files

Comment: These are the all steps and it should work if you are following all the steps. are you still facing the same issue?